# Mongoose cannot connect to Openshift MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**The logs in OpenShift displays MongoError cannot connect to undefined:27017**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var url = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var connect = function () {

    mongoose.connect(url);
};

connect();

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function(error){

    console.log("Error loading the db - "+ error);
});

db.on('disconnected', connect);
```

Comment: are you sure you have the process variables defined?

Comment: I thought they are defined the moment i run the deployment in OpenShift. Are they not?
If not, can you teach me how to define them. Thank you sir!